# What causes backup in Windows Vista to cancel itself?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-backup

I've been having backup nightmares a lot lately.  Using the standard Windows Vista backup software.  For ages I've been trying to get an initial backup to DVD to run successfully.  Previously it had been failing with some kind of file system error partway through filling the third DVD.

Last night I started a backup.  It was taking too long, so after it had filled three DVDs I put my computer into standby in order to continue today.  However, when I came back to it, it was displaying "File backup was cancelled".  I certainly didn't cancel it, so what might cause this?

(Before you ask, I pressed Ctrl or Shift or something like that to wake my computer up from standby, so know it wasn't down to my pressing a key that might have triggered a button in the dialog.)

Comment: 1. Interrupting the backup probably caused the issue. 2. Try one of the free backup/imaging programs, such as Macrium Reflect... I find them faster.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 1. That doesn't tell me anything.  What might have interrupted the backup?  As I began to say, I certainly didn't interrupt it. 2. Thanks - I'll check that program out when I get the chance.

Comment: *You* interrupted it by putting it in standby. That allows various timers to expire. During standby, the RTC still advances.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Then the timer would have equally expired if I'd just left the computer idle without putting it into standby. So it appears what you're really saying is that it cancels itself if it's left idle for a certain length of time (and that this time is measured using the RTC). If this is the case, you could post it as an answer.  Even better would be an insight into how long the timeout is.